# How to select graphs with specific vertex conditions?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I'm trying to select graphs that have a path with the following conditions:

1. Include vertices `a1, a2, b1, b2`.
2. Vertices `a1` and `a2` should be neighbors, and vertices `b1` and `b2` should be neighbors.
3. Vertices in the middle should have a degree of 2.
4. Vertices `a1, a2` when they are at two ends of a path, one can have a degree more than 2,
   but not both. Similar for `b1, b2`.

I'm stuck on how to neatly do it as there are many conditions. Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this? I'm looking for something fast as well since the number of graphs is large. For the example graphs below, the results should be something like `{True, False, True, True, False,False}`.

```
style = {a1 <-> a2 -> Directive[Red, Thick], 
   b1 <-> b2 -> Directive[Blue, Thick]};
g1 = Graph[{1 <-> b1, b1 <-> a1, a1 <-> 1, a1 <-> a2, a2 <-> 5, 
    5 <-> b2, b2 <-> b1}, VertexLabels -> Automatic, EdgeStyle -> style
   ];
g2 = Graph[{1 <-> b1, b1 <-> a1, a1 <-> 1, a1 <-> a2, a2 <-> 5, 
    5 <-> b1}, VertexLabels -> Automatic, 
   EdgeStyle -> a1 <-> a2 -> Directive[Red, Thick]]; 

g3 = Graph[{1 <-> b1, b1 <-> a1, a1 <-> 1, a1 <-> a2, a2 <-> 5, 
    5 <-> 6, 6 <-> b2, b2 <-> b1}, VertexLabels -> Automatic, 
   EdgeStyle -> style];
g4 = Graph[{1 <-> 5, 5 <-> a1, a1 <-> 1, a1 <-> a2, a2 <-> b1, 
    b1 <-> b2, b2 <-> 5}, VertexLabels -> Automatic, 
   EdgeStyle -> style];
g5 = Graph[{1 <-> a2, a2 <-> a1, a1 <-> 1, a1 <-> b1, b1 <-> b2, 
    b2 <-> 5, 5 <-> a2}, VertexLabels -> Automatic, 
   EdgeStyle -> style];
g6 = Graph[{1 <-> 5, 5 <-> a1, a1 <-> 1, a1 <-> a2, a2 <-> b1, 
    b1 <-> b2, b2 <-> 5, b1 <-> 6}, VertexLabels -> Automatic, 
   EdgeStyle -> style];
 graphList = {g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6}
(*result={True, False, True, True, False,False}*)
```

[image]

Comment: "how to neatly do it" - what have you tried so far though?

Comment: @MarcoB I'm not at my PC right now.
Here is what I have done: first, find all possible vertex pairs and then use `FindPath` to identify all paths between two vertices of a pair (essentially finding all paths in a graph). Next, use `ContainsAll` to filter paths that include `a1, a2, b1, b2`. Finally, check the `VertexDegree` to verify the condition.